# Trigger jQuery click function in angular custom directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to call this `$('.modify-activity-dates').trigger('click');` inside my custom directive function like this

```
$scope.loadActivityModule = function(){

        if($scope.isFlightAdded() || $scope.hotelAvailable()){

                var location ='ComponentSupportAction.do?method=loadActivityResultsPage';
                var form = '<input type="hidden" name="transectionId" value="'+getSession()+'">';
                $('<form action="' + location + '" method="POST">' + form + '</form>').appendTo($(document.body)).submit();

                var activities = $rootScope.productCart.cart.addedActivitylList;

                try{                        
                    if(activities.length != 0) { 
                        $('.modify-activity-dates').trigger('click');                                                               
                    }                       
                } catch(e) {

                }                                       
            } else {                                        
                bookingEngineActivityApp_SharedService.reverseShowBookingEngineActivity();
            }
    }
```

When I click on an image of the pop up it disappears(that part already working) and should trigger the jQuery click in the background page which I can't make it happen.

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3wJh.png)

Comment: what is the value of `activities.length` at the beginning of the `try` block?

Comment: did `activities.length != 0` is getting `true` ;)

Comment: @sfletche - 'activities' is an array.

Comment: @K.Toress - ow ban :D it's not about that if condition but the jquery syntax.

Comment: share a simplified http://plnkr.co/edit/ , it will be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your program, I am assuming that you are including JQuery.xxx.js in your <head> tag using <script> tags

As per the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function

> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file.

After that you can use **angular.element**

```
angular.element('.modify-activity-dates').trigger('click');
```